# SOAP API - RequestRecipientToken not working in production with error 113. Other service call works

Tags: docusignapi

SOAP service calls to `RequestRecipientToken`

---

return `error code 113` with `error reason "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."  Other service works to create/retrieve envelope.`

This is not working in demo account and other production account.

> Asking DocuSign support to turn off In Session Signing Certificate.  Recall having to do something similar with other production account.

Answer (score 0):

If all other SOAP calls authenticate successfully, but the RequestRecipientToken call is failing with a credentials error, the relevant setting is `Don't enforce In Session Certificate` which should be checked for your account.

As this setting cannot be toggled on the customer side, you will need to open a [DocuSign Support Case](https://support.docusign.com/) requesting that option be enabled for your account. When opening the case, please provide all impacted account numbers, and clarify which are in Demo and which are in Production.